# Table with many columns (XLTabular)

Tags: tables, longtable, xltabular

I want to create my table using package `xltabular`, since it has a nice compatibility to be able to autofit into page margin. My table has many columns, and by the rule from my institution, I may not make this table in a landscape format, so I have to stick with potrait orientation.

This is the table screenshot, generated from Microsoft Excel.
[image: table screenshot]

For now, the MWE is using `longtable` package. Altough this is quite nice to look, it still goes off the margin. This is the code and I will attach the screenshot below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=4cm,
  top=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill} % set margin
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft} % set margin
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|m{0.15\textwidth}|r|m{0.15\textwidth}|m{0.1\textwidth}|m{0.1\textwidth}|r|r|r|r|}
        \caption{Hasil Perbandingan \textit{Pitch} pada lagu Twinkle-Twinkle Little Star di Model Pertama}
        \label{tab:diff-twinkle-model1}\\
        
        \hline
        
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{No}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pitch Result}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dist}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Match}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Diff1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Diff2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Len\_match}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{len\_diff1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{len\_diff2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{percentage}} \bigstrut\\

        \textbf{1} & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] & 2     & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] & []    & []    & 14    & 0     & 0     & 100.00\% \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \textbf{2} & [0, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57] & 521   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57] & [58]  & [44, 45] & 13    & 1     & 2     & 71.43\% \bigstrut\\
        \hline
\textbf{3} & [0, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59] & 550   & [0, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] & [46, 47] & [59]  & 12    & 2     & 1     & 64.29\% \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \textbf{4} & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55] & 637   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55] & [56, 57, 58] & []    & 11    & 3     & 0     & 57.14\% \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This is the `longtable` output. Notice the red lines. It indicates the page margin. The longtable goes beyond the margin. 
[image: longtable output]

When I try to implement `xltabular`, I add this to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
```

However, the output does not look so nice. This is the sample current output, with overlapping column text.
[image: xltabular column output]

This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l | Z | r | Z | Z | Z | r | r | r | r @{}}
    
    \caption{Hasil Perbandingan \textit{Pitch} pada lagu Twinkle-Twinkle Little Star di Model Pertama}
    \label{tab:diff-twinkle-model1} \\
    \toprule
    {\textbf{No}} & {\textbf{unique-pitch}} & {\textbf{distance}} & {\textbf{Match}} & {\textbf{diff\_kurang}} & {\textbf{diff\_lebih}} & {\textbf{len\_match}} & {\textbf{len\_kurang}} & {\textbf{len\_lebih}} & {\textbf{percentage}} \bigstrut\\
    
    \midrule    
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
\end{xltabular}
```

What can I do to fix my table? Should I fix my `longtable` or create a new one using `xltabular`?

Comment: You could rotate the column headers in order to save some space and avoid the overlapping text you currently get with xltabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may liked the following result:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

It is produced by:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={4cm, 3cm},
            vmargin={3cm, 3cm}
              ]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begingroup
\footnotesize  % <--- size of fonts in the table
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\dimexpr\linewidth-3pt}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}c|L|r|L|L|L|r|r|r|r|}
\caption{Hasil Perbandingan \textit{Pitch} pada lagu Twinkle-Twinkle Little Star di Model Pertama}
\label{tab:diff-twinkle-model1} \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\thead{No}  & \thead{Pitch\\ Result}& \thead{Dist}  & \thead{Match}
            & \thead{Diff1}         & \thead{Diff2} & \thead{Len\_\\ match}
            & \thead{len\_\\ diff1} & \thead{len\_\\ diff2} & \thead{\%}\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
1   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] 
    & 2     & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] 
    & [ ]   & [ ]       & 14    & 0 & 0 & 100.00    \\
    \hline
2   & [0, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57] 
    & 521   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57] 
    & [58]  & [44, 45]  & 13    & 1     & 2     & 71.43             \\
        \hline
3   & [0, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59] 
    & 550   & [0, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] 
    & [46, 47] & [59]   & 12    & 2     & 1     & 64.29              \\
        \hline
4   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55] 
    & 637   & [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55] 
    & [56, 57, 58] 
    & [ ]   & 11        & 3     & 0     & 57.14                     \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

*Note*: size of fonts can be reduced to predefined sizes by commands `\small` or `\footnotesize` and `\tiny`, or increased to predefined sizes by commands `\large`, `\Large` or `\huge` and `\Huge`. Beside these sizes you can define (own) font size by command `\fontsize{<font size>}{<baseline size>}\selectfont`.

Mentioned commands are switches (not environments as you wrongly used in your document example), so after it used font are changed as long until you not return to normal font size by command `\normalsize` or to the end of group, in which you change font size, as is done in above MWE (Minimal Worlking Example).

Comment: out of topic question, can I make all the font size smaller in that table?  If it is possible, how to do so?

Comment: @DionisiusPratama, I already reduce font size from your `\small` to ˙\footnotesize`. Even smaller font are  `\scriptsize` and `\tiny`.  For use one of them you need to replace `\footnotesize` with selected one. However, bear in mind, that smaller font size can become hard to read.

Comment: @DionisiusPratama, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea now.