# Why the header is not following the large body using Longtable?

Tags: longtable, paper-size

I'm trying to put a very long table in a latex document, it works the table is in more than a page but its header is not following the content size.
[image]

The code is the following:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|l|l|}
 \caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
 \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long}}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
 \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot
 X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
 X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
 X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
 X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
....
....
 \end{longtable}
```

Could someone help-me?
Thank you all folks

Comment: How many time you compile your document? Your code fragment gives expected correct result, however, it is not related to showed image at all.

Comment: It was compiled 3 times,  can I use \resizebox with longtable to make horizontaly fit in the paper ?

Comment: No. You should use for example `xltabular˛` environemnt (combination of `tabularx` and `longtable`, or new `longtblr` defined in the `tabularray` package. But this is not addressed in your question.

Comment: An example of use of the `xltabular` you can see in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593830/table-with-many-columns-xltabular/593834#593834

Comment: Please fix your example so that it is a complete small document that produces the problem shown, it is much harder to debug a fragment

Comment: @user2535338 never use `\resizebox` with tables, it can't work at all with `longtable` and with `tabular` it does not give errors but can not produce good results.

Comment: I've explained  better in a new question ```https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604768/how-to-resize-the-longtable-in-latex```

Comment: the new question is completely different question: that's about how to linebreak  long strings of non-words. Do you still have a question about longtable chunks getting the same width? if so please edit the question to make an answer, if not, please delete this question.