# How to resize the longtable in latex?

Tags: longtable, wrap

I'm trying fit a `longtable` in latex, I've searched but all the examples was didn't worked for me because of the `` \begin{longtable}`[c]`{|l|l|l|l|l|} ``, the output is the following:
[image]

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\title{A longtable example}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
\hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{long}}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
 \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
        zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It would be great if the content of the table could be wrapped, which could help to fit also...

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Use the `xltabular` environment, from the homonymous package. It brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: Does It  allows the multi rows?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. However noote that a multirow cannot break across pages.This being said, the syntax is the same as for longtable (firsthead, lastfoot, &c.).

Comment: It didn't worked,  the table is out of the paper either

Comment: because your cells contents doesn't allow hyphenation. Replace used "word" with natural ones.

Comment: Did you use `X`column types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Real content of table is unknow. If texts in table cells have natural worlds (in MWE below are generated by package `lipsum`), it can be broken in multi line texts:

[image]

MWE, using `xltabular`, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|} }
\caption{Long table caption.}
\label{long}                            \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
 \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\multirow{30}{=}{\lipsum[66]}
            &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \cline{2-5}
            &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \hline
\lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] &   \lipsum[66] \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works partially, In the table that I have, it has some bulltet points which I would like to put them in different lines. I'm using tabular inside the cell but it doesn't allow to  wrap the text anymore

Comment: @user2535338, no, my answer, if it is properly used, woks completely. Don't nest tabular inside X cells. If you like to have billets (a list) inside, than use `enumitem` package. However, problems with lists inside cells is not mentioned in your question. You may ask new question about this.

Comment: There is a way to change the caption of this table?  For example insted of `Table: long table` to  `Frame:  long  frame`  just this table without affecting the other Tables? Thank you

Comment: @user2535338, yes, it is. There on site already exist answer from `tabularray package author, which solve this problem. Just use it.

Comment: I've tried  the caption packge but is having the same bug and the tabularray dos not work either I've posted  it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609288/140575

Comment: @user2535338, sorry, this site is question - answer site, not forume. So, if yo have new problems, please ask new question. On this way other people, who may help you will see your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your `longtable` design suffers from a number of serious design errors.

- Never encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment.
- The `l` column type doesn't allow automatic line breaking. Having a table with 5 columns, each of which contains very long "words" which aren't allowed to be line-broken and updated, is a guarantee for an unmitigated  (typographic) disaster.

  In the code below, I therefore replace `l` with

  ```
  p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
  ```

  where the width is calculated so that the table will occupy the full width of the textblock.
- Moreover, the long words in the cells are of the following five types:

  ```
  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz 
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
  cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc 
  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  ```

  Unsurprisingly (to me at least!), LaTeX does *not* appear to have been informed how to line-break and hyphenate these "words". Actually, very much to my surprise, LaTeX does appear to "know" how to line-break the word "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc". I have no idea why.

  If your document contains long words for which LaTeX does not appear to know how they might be hyphenated, you must provide the missing hyphenation information via `\hyphenation` directives.
- We're still not done! For various historical reasons, TeX (and subsequent descendants such as pdftex and xetex) will not hyphenate words that are longer than about 40 characters, if memory serves me well. Since your "words" all exceed the character count limit, the document must be compiled under LuaLaTeX, which has a much larger limit on hyphenation-related word lengths.

---

Making the required adjustment leads to the following output:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e}
\hyphenation{% provide a list of hyphenation exceptions
zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzzzzzzzzz
xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
%ccccccccccc-ccccccccccc-ccccccccccc-ccccccc
vvvvvvvvvv-vvvvvvvvvv-vvvvvvvvvv-vvvvvvv
bbbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{|*{5}{%
   p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}}
\caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
\hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \thetable}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{Chave} & \textbf{X}   & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{X}\\
 \hline
 \endhead

 % \hline
 % \endfoot

 % \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot
 
%% body of longtable
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```