# How to set a specific word in `Table` caption in `xltabular` so that it be recognized by the indexes

Tags: captions, indexing, xltabular

I'm writing a master thesis. So I'm having trouble with the long tables and frames. I'm using `xltabular` because it can deal with tables of multiple pages, and I need to change some `Tables #` to `Frames #` but it's following the table number and not the frames, and its also putting them in the tables list index and not in the Frame  List index.
**Edited:** MWE, using xltabular, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}



\begin{document}


\captionsetup[table]{name = Frame}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|}}
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{long} \\   
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup


\captionsetup[table]{name = Table}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|}}
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{long} \\   
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\captionsetup[table]{name = Frame}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|}}
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{long} \\   
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup


\captionsetup[table]{name = Table}
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{L|}}
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{long} \\   
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you  you all :)

Comment: I have trouble compiling your tex file.

Comment: Try now, I've changed the code

Comment: Still got the same error: `! Misplaced \noalign.` for Line 52: `l.52 \end{xltabular}`

Comment: Here is not showing this error

Comment: After each `\label` a double backslash (`\\ `) is missing, hence the error message.

Comment: Changed again !

Comment: You need to define new list of frames. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things. Your question seems to be duplicate to this one.